# Disable select boxes on load if form is in read-only mode using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Lotus Notes view with several documents, when I select a document, the document opens the form which has a embedded view in it, with select boxes. I want the select boxes to be seen when the opened document is in edit mode, not in read-only mode (preferably using JavaScript), the select button column has HTML written to it.

`<input type=checkbox id=\"viewselecteddoc\" onclick=\"setcheckval()\" style=\"border:0px\" value=\""+@Text (@DocumentUniqueID)+"\">`

I thought of writing JavaScript, on `onload` of the form, which will take the handle of the parent view and checks if edit document is present then show it, else hide it, will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by following below methods:

Try to make a new embedded view same like the one earlier, but remove the select box column, in this view and in the main form, while choosing the embedded view, use by formula and then write the formula, @if(@isdocbeingedited;"the view name which is to be shown on edit";"the view which has to be shown on readonly").

Hope this works.